# Copiar dados de uma tabela para outra sem precisar digitar campo a campo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alguém sabe o comando SQL que copio os dados de uma tabela para outra tabela, sem precisar explicitar todos os campos da tabela original? Eu sei que existe uma maneira mas me esqueci como faz e não consegui encontrar na net, se alguém souber, ficaria muito grato se pudesse compartilhar aqui comigo, desde já agradeço a atenção. #SQL

Comment: para qual banco de dados você esta tentando fazer?

Comment: @PabloVargas SQL

Comment: SQL Server? MySQL? noSQL?

Comment: @rray SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer de 3 formas.

```
-- sql tabela volátil só existira em tempo de execução
declare @HIERARQUIA table
(
    [ID_HIERARQUIA] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [MICRO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DESCR] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [MACRO] [int] NULL,
    [POSICAO] [varchar](250) NOT NULL
)

-- 1ª 
-- copia para tabela temporaria ...  ficar no banco tempdb até que finalize o execução.
select * into #HIERARQUIA from HIERARQUIA ;

-- 2ª 
-- copia para tabela volátil só existira em tempo de execução
insert into @HIERARQUIA
select * from #HIERARQUIA;

-- 3ª 
-- copia para uma tabela da base de dados
insert into HIERARQUIA
select * from HIERARQUIA ;
```

Resumindo. Você vai precisar criar uma tabela com os mesmo campos ou utilizar uma temporária e usa o `*` no **Select** , isso faz o mapeamento dos seus campos para uma outra tabela automaticamente.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver usando `SELECT * INTO`, agradeço a todos pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

No SQL Server e em outros banco pode usar o select into(com algumas diferenças de sintaxe)

```
SELECT * INTO nova_tabela FROM outra_tabela
```

[Inserting Rows by Using SELECT INTO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)